# How to make stretchable bootstrap div according to mobile, tablet, desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap framework and found it very interesting. I have seen a website that is working awesome on mobile, tablet and laptop at the same time. I saw four div in the page in one line and when a user stretch the page, it hides the two div and make it nice view able on the tablet and when i stretch it more according to the mobile size it hides the 3 div and display only one with nice css effects.

Please have a look on the following three images and see the desired effects that i need to achieve.

[image: FirstImage]

[image: SecondImage]

[image: ThirdIamge]

I just need to implement the same using bootstrap. Please anyone guide or share the sample code to understand. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: post what you tryed..

Comment: This seems to be a common bootstrap feature, which can be achieved easily using rows and cols. Learn about bootstrap grid and show your attempts.

Comment: @Sarath, just started learning and this is my starting point. If you can share any sample code or tutorial to achieve the same thing well be warm welcome, thanks.

Comment: @RaufAbid by copying someone else code you will never learn. Better go on and read bootstrap basic and start using them with low example and then go with these. Believe me its so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to achieve the desired results. Bootstrap gives you control on how your div block will behave on different devices or screen sizes.

Check out the code below.

```
<div class="contaniner">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
        <h4 class="h4"> Some text Here...</h4>
        <p> Some more text Here...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
        <h4 class="h4"> Some text Here...</h4>
        <p> Some more text Here...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
        <h4 class="h4"> Some text Here...</h4>
        <p> Some more text Here...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
        <h4 class="h4"> Some text Here...</h4>
        <p> Some more text Here...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its awesome. I exactly need the same thing. Just please share the bootstrap documentation/tutorial page where i can get the same above code for learning. Many thanks :)

Comment: Please use this link for complete documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

If you are looking for video tutorials here's a quick link: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=314m7YBRFvQ&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXd4xnk-j5FGhHjUv1LsF0V

Go through the playlist and you will get the concept in no time...